# Rails 4 Devise Sessions Controller Unknown Format

Tags: session, devise, respond-to

I'm encountering this error :

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

Each time i'm posting to Rails 4 Devise Sessions Api Controller.

Here is the gist as well as logs, can anyone please help me with this ?

https://gist.github.com/jsooriah/8574465

Best,

j.